# Regex colnames and grouping in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, melt

I have this data frame:

```
id <- c(0,1,2,3,4)
groupA_sample1_values <- c(10,11,12,13,14)
groupA_sample2_values <- c(20,21,22,23,24)
groupA_sample3_values <- c(30,31,32,33,34)
groupB_sample1_values <- c(40,41,42,43,44)
groupB_sample2_values <- c(50,51,52,53,54)
groupB_sample3_values <- c(60,61,62,63,64)

df <- data.frame(id, 
                 groupA_sample1_values,
                 groupA_sample2_values,
                 groupA_sample3_values,
                 groupB_sample1_values,
                 groupB_sample2_values,
                 groupB_sample3_values)

df
```

and I am trying to obtain another table with these columns:
id, group, sample, value.
I belive I would have to extract the name groupA/groupB  with regex, and the same for the sample number, and the melt it to a new data frame, but I'm not sure how to approach it.
Any help?

Comment: Hi! it would very helpful if you provide an example of what you want to achieve, how the resulting data frame should look like

Comment: @MarceloAvila Thanks man, I'll take it into account the next time I ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
library( tidyverse )
df %>%
  pivot_longer( -id,
                names_to = c("group", "sample" ),
                names_pattern = "group(.)_sample(.)_values",
                values_to = "value" )

# # A tibble: 30 x 4
#      id group sample value
#   <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
# 1     0 A     1         10
# 2     0 A     2         20
# 3     0 A     3         30
# 4     0 B     1         40
# 5     0 B     2         50
# 6     0 B     3         60
# 7     1 A     1         11
# 8     1 A     2         21
# 9     1 A     3         31
#10     1 B     1         41
```